# Inserir um ponto no penúltimo item da variável

Tags: javascript, array, loop, for

Tenho uma variavel com o valor "14013" e estou tentando inserir um ponto para ficar com o seguinte valor "140.13" em meu loop.

```
for (var i in teste) {
  for (var j in (teste2[teste[i]])) {
       valorFinal[j] = resultado1 + resultado2;
       //valorFinal[j] precisa ter um ponto antes do penultimo item 
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
for (i in teste) {
    for (j in (teste2[teste[i]])) {
        valorFinal[j] = (resultado1 + resultado2);
        var res = valorFinal[j].toString();
        var dec = Math.floor(res.length - 2);
        var resp = res.substring(0, dec) + "." + res.substring(dec);
    }
}
```

Acho que isso resolve.

Comment: Editei a resposta.
Agora vai dar certo.

Comment: Agora deu certo @Vitor, muito obrigado pela ajuda amigo!

Comment: Porquê `var dec = Math.floor(res.length - 2);`?

Answer (score 2):

Tente isso, criei uma função `insertDot()`, que recebe como argumento o número que você quiser:

```js
var a = 14013;

function insertDot(a){
  a = a.toString(); // Transforma em String 
  var beforeDot = a.substring(0, a.length-2); // Captura do primeiro ao penúltimo caractere
  var afterDot = a.substring(a.length-2, a.length); // Captura o penúltimo ao último caractere
  return parseFloat(beforeDot + "." + afterDot); // retorna um NÚMERO com com o ponto inserido
}

document.body.innerHTML += insertDot(a);
document.body.innerHTML += "<br>";
document.body.innerHTML += insertDot(a) * 2;
```

Assim, basta fazer:

```
function insertDot(a){
  a = a.toString();
  return parseFloat(a.substring(0, a.length-2)+"."+a.substring(a.length-2, a.length));
}
for (var i in teste) {
  for (var j in (teste2[teste[i]])) {
       valorFinal[j] = resultado1 + resultado2;
       valorFinal[j] = insertDot(valorFinal[j]);
  }
}
```

Com um segundo argumento que recebe a posição do ponto, como sugeriu Sergio:

```js
var a = 14013;

function insertDot(a, pos){
  a = a.toString(); 
  if(pos > 0){
     a = parseFloat(a.substring(0, pos) + "." + a.substring(pos, a.length));
  }else{
     a = parseFloat(a.substring(0, a.length+pos) + "." + a.substring(a.length+pos, a.length));
  }
  return a;
}

document.body.innerHTML += insertDot(a, 1);
document.body.innerHTML += "<br>";
document.body.innerHTML += insertDot(a, -2);
document.body.innerHTML += "<br>";
document.body.innerHTML += insertDot(a, -2) * 2;
```

Comment: Gostei, se tivesse um segundo argumento com a posição do ponto, tipo `inserDot(192, -1)`  então ficava bem flexivel. Mas parece que o AP já está satisfeito com a outra resposta.

Comment: @Sergio, editei a resposta apenas a nível de posteriores usos por outros usuários. Obrigado pela sugestão.

Comment: Muito obrigado pela ajuda pessoal, testei e também me ajudou!